# GPU usage drops causing FPS drop spike

Tags: cpu, gpu, gaming, lag, fps

I've been experiencing some stuttering/micro freezes while playing a certain videogame, BF4 to be precise. When running at different video qualities, ranging from low to ultra, the game scores 60fps smoothly, just to drop to below 10fps for like micro seconds, and goes back to 60fps. This issue is restricted to BF4, other games have not this issue.

Specs

```
Intel i7 6700HQ 2.6Ghz
nVidia 960M 1GB
16GB RAM
OS Windows 10 creator update
everthing is stock and not overclocked
```

Using "High performance" power plan, with min and max states of the cpu set at 100% in the advanced settings.

Here's the usage graph got from MSI afterburner.
[image: MSI afterburner usage graph]

Does anyone have some ideas how to troubleshoot this issue and know what's causing the GPU usage to drop.

Comment: CPU or GPU thermal throttling? Try using the GPU-z and Coretemp programs to see if either are overheating.

Comment: look if you have DPC issues (check it with LatencyMon) while this happens

Comment: Going to try both, and get back to you

Comment: ok, have you tried it? does LatencyMon show you DPC spikes?

Comment: For LatencyMon, I don't how what data could be useful for you to know from it, but for the record, Highest latency measured was `1843,75309 µs` tested at `HIGH_LEVEL IRQL`

Comment: As for temperatures, CPU is running at 80 degrees (Celsius) and GPU at 70. Temperatures are constant, and not influencing fps drops from analyzing the performance graph as the fps remain on 60fps. GPU drops are the main thing causing fps drop spikes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of reports about Battlefield 4 problems of low fps, which I would
guess are due to this game inefficiently using the CPU for rendering, rather
than the GPU.

Some people say that while running Battlefield 4, the CPU temperature may
spike momentarily, which will cause their motherboard to throttle the CPU
for a short while. The only solution then is to get a better CPU fan.

There are nearly as many solutions as reports, which I will try to catalog
below:

1. **Windows**: Update drivers; uninstalling the HD audio driver may help;
   unpark your cores using
   [registry modifications](http://thehowtoman.com/how-to-unpark-cpu-for-battlefield-4/)
   or the [Unparking utility](http://www.coderbag.com/programming-c/disable-cpu-core-parking-utility).
2. **BIOS** : Update to the latest version and turn off all power-saving features.
   Depending on the manufacturer, were mentioned: Cool 'n Quit, CE1, Core C6,
   while HPC (Hardware Performance Computing) is to be turned on.
3. Use [**EVGA Precision XOC**](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/evga_precision.html) to enable kboost
4. **Nvidia** : Clean install the latest driver;
   in the Nvidia Control Panel go to Manage 3D settings -> Program Settings and select Battlefield 4 in the drop-down box and scroll down to "Power management mode" and select "Prefer maximum performance" and then Apply and Close.
5. **Uninstall MSI Afterburner** (some people had problems with it)
6. **Origin** : In Application settings -> Origin in Game, disable Origin in game;
   in Settings -> General turn off Cloud Storage.
7. **Battlefield 4** : In the root folder, normally
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games\Battlefield 4`.
   create a file named `user.cfg` that will contain:

**user.cfg**:

```
WorldRender.TransparencyShadowmapsEnable 0
WorldRender.MotionBlurEnable 0
WorldRender.MotionBlurForceOn 0
WorldRender.MotionBlurFixedShutterTime 0
WorldRender.MotionBlurMax 0
WorldRender.MotionBlurQuality 0
WorldRender.MotionBlurMaxSampleCount 0
WorldRender.SpotLightShadowmapEnable 0
WorldRender.SpotLightShadowmapResolution 256
WorldRender.LightTileCsPathEnable 0
RenderDevice.ForceRenderAheadLimit 0
PostProcess.DynamicAOEnable 0
PerfOverlay.DrawFps 0
GameTime.MaxVariableFps 59.99
```

Comment: Going to try these, getting back with updates after

Comment: A agree with your statement regarding inefficiency. As for the drivers, specific known-to-be-good ones may help more than having the latest version.